# Intellij cannot debug cucumber + serenity test run

Tags: debugging, testing, intellij-idea, cucumber

I got java cucumber + serenity project in Intellij
I configured the maven run configure:
Working directory: xxxxx
Command line: clean verify "xxxxx"

The run configure works fine before, I can use it run test as well as fire up the debug mode.

However, one of sudden, I cannot run the debug mode anymore. Even though I clicked the debugged button (green little bug) it never stops at the break point.

It still stops if I added break point to java.lang Object class, but it never stops at any break point from actual test methods, very weird...any one can help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surefire starts a new jvm to run tests (a fork). You are debugging the jvm that starts the second jvm, not the jvm that runs the tests.

Either change the fork mode or attach a debugger to the forked jvm.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I tried to add "-DforkCount=0" to my run configure as VM Options, but the test execution just failed straight away.

Actually, from my previous run, I can see the debugger already connected to target VM, the address is same as the run VM, but it just not stopped at the break point, very weird.

Comment: Check the basics. Such as 1) are you using the same maven version from the docs 2) same plugin version from the docs 3) did you try both suggestions or only one?

Comment: I finally resolved issue by changing to a different type of run configure instead of maven one. But thank you for your suggestion.